# Why do me and another computer in my house have a different IP addresses

Tags: ip

I want to make a LAN Minecraft server with my sister but it appeared that I was on the IP 192.168.0.24 and she was on 192.168.0.16. I am using an ethernet connection and she is on WiFi. Is there a way I can change my IP?

Comment: if you are having trouble connecting, check your wifi settings to make sure a setting called AP Isolation, or Client isolation is turned off.  enabling isolation will prevent machines on the wifi from connecting to other systems on your network whether they are on wifi or ethernet. the setting is designed for coffee shops and other shared environments where you don't want people to try to hack eachother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two computers cannot have the same IP address. You are both on the same subnet (.0) and you each have a separate IP (.16 and .24). This is entirely normal and correct.

The Minecraft Server can /should recognize different IP addresses.

Comment: Absolutely right.